# Anyone know where I can buy Seder Tikkun Chatzos by R' Sraya Deblitzky?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books

Full title:
"סדר תקון חצות: כסדר האריז"ל ... עם הדינים השייכים ולוח תמידי של זמן חצות לילה ומיום זמן תיקון חצות. ונוסף בסופו הלכות קריעה על המקדש"

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty small. [Here's a link](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=79820760835597113072).

Answer (score 1):

One of his זצ"ל other ספרים has his number from when he was still in this world: 0505272141
And the people that put the sefer together 0544264077. Maybe they can help. If not, ask if they can put you to through someone who can. Or try Otzar HaChochma.

Comment: https://www.otzar.org/wotzar/Book.aspx?11886&